# Using jQuery to target a specific link in the navigation

Tags: jquery

I am working with a dynamic navigation and need to be able to target one specific link to open in a new window.

I need some help with the jQuery to do this.

For example I would like to be able to target the navigation item of **Education** which has a link of **http://www.foo.com/education** and have it open in new window when I click on it.

Would appreciate some assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$("a[href='http://www.foo.com/education']").attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: It should work but it doesn't. Please take a look: http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/education/ and click on the Global Health Courses link. It should open in a new window.

Comment: you need to wrap it in a document ready function
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("a[href='http://www.foo.com/education']").attr('target', '_blank');
      });

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open( $("a[href='example.com']").attr('href') );
```

Answer (score 1):

or just

<a href="http://www.food.com/education" class="education" target="_blank">Education</a>

don't know why you would need to do this with jQuery.

Comment: because this is not a static link. It is generated dynamically and I don't have the option to add that.